# GraphApi module present in pyfacebook or not

Tags: python, pyfacebook

i have installed pyfacebook as well as python sdk even the i am getting error as follows

when using this code

```
import facebook
token = 'my token'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
friend_list = [friend['name'] for friend in friends['data']]
print friend_list
```

error that i am facing is

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphAPI'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I install the `facebook` module using `easy_install facebook`. It worked when I ran the following instead:

`git clone https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk.git`
`pip install facebook-sdk`